# json parsing in android

Tags: android, json

How to parse the following JSON in android ?

```
{"Servicedata":{"services_description":"Absolutely awesome compound on 50+ acres","services_image":"http:\/\/192.168.100.81\/watchdog_webservice\/service_images\/shop1.jpg","service_userid":"1"}}
```

Comment: Don't ask question without google it...

Comment: Put the code. Let's see what you tried to parse this json....??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONObject servicedata = object.getJSONObject("Servicedata");
String desc = servicedata.getString("services_description");
String image = servicedata.getString("services_image");
String id = servicedata.getString("service_userid");
```

Comment: thanxxx bro u helped me again .. n m sry m a newbiee :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the source of the JSON data? The below is for parsing JSON from a URL.

```
 try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```